# Should we use Java 8 now for Android development?

Tags: android

The other questions about this are more than two years old, therefore I would like to know the status of Java 8 with Android.

Specifically I want to use lambda expressions starting with only that. I want to refactor code like the following into lambda expressions:

```
 Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                missileX = ufoX;
                resetRecent();
                waitForUfoTimer = false;
            }
        }, randomize(20000, 18000));
```

Comment: I very much doubt that a “yes” or a “no” could be the answer to this question. It will have to depend on a lot of factors like your audience and your requirements. Each development project will have to weigh the pros and cons for themselves.

Comment: In my experience, enabling Java 8 slowed down my builds enough that disabled it for now. The de-sugaring step added about 10 seconds to my build. Your mileage may vary. Future releases of the gradle plugin and android tools will surely improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in my opinion you should. It brings in some nice features like lambda expressions or method references or streams (not supported for every version, though) that make the code neater. On the other hand, neatness may not be seen as an advantage for some as it can be considered less readable. In addition, your Android plugin for Gradle must be at least `3.0.0` that may not be an option for every project.

As mentioned earlier, some features of `JAVA 8` are not supported if your `minSdk` version is lower than 24.

What is supported for any `minSdk`:

1. Lambda expressions
2. Method references
3. Type annotations
4. Default and static interface methods.
5. Repeating annotations

For more information please refer to - https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support

Answer (score 4):

> Should we use Java 8 now for Android development?

Yes. You need to add below lines in module build.gradle

```
android {
   compileOptions {
       sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   }
 ..
}
```

Now by default android studio supports to use Java8 language features. Now you don't need Jack for this. You must have Android Studio Plugin 3.0.0 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using the language features such as lambda expressions works absolutely fine. Just change your settings to reflect version 8.

However, some java 8 apis aren't available for older android versions. An example of this would be java LocalDate. If you target a high enough android version (26 I believe) then this will work, otherwise you'll have to use java Date or joda timsb